# Binding different item source to each row of combo box column

Tags: wpf, combobox

I tried to bind a different item source in ComboBoxColumn, but it shows the dropdown as empty. It worked in TemplateColumn. Can anyone explain about the behaviour of comboxcolumn?

Comment: do you mean DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: Yes . It is DataGridComboxColumn .

Comment: what do you want exactly ,, put xaml and cs

Comment: I want xaml  and also know about how it will easily achieved in TemplateColumn ,but the same requirement not worked in ComboBoxColumn

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of code. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) for detailed information.

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>

...

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order Status"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you please explain , why we need to edit its ElemenStyle and EditElementStyle of ComboBoxColumn? or please provide any link related to this for better understanding

Comment: I have improved/edited my answer. See it, you'll get your answers.